# EBNF: one or more and zero or more, in no particular order

Tags: ebnf

In an EBNF grammar I have two tokens `shape` and `attr`. How would I express that `shape` should occur one or more times and `attr` zero or more times, but in no particular order, i.e.:

```
shape1 shape2 shape3
attr1 shape1
shape1 attr1
shape1 shape2 attr1 shape3
```

Would all be parsed, but

attr1 attr2 ..

would not?

Comment: To clarify I should say 'express that `shape` should occur one or more times and `attr` zero or more times *in a sequence*'

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

```
seq = shape as_seq | attr seq
as_seq = (shape | attr)*
```

does the trick

(where `shape` and `attr` are defined elsewhere in the grammar.
e.g. `shape = 'a'` and `attr = 'b'`. Then 'a' 'ab' 'aaab' 'bbbab' will all match but 'b' 'bb' 'bbb..' etc will not)